# unable to set react-select-async-paginate initial value

Tags: reactjs

I am using a react-select-async-paginate. It's working on form submit. I am facing problem in **edit form**. When I click on edit button, I am able to show all the values in their tags except the select. I have made a few attempts to show the selected value but no luck.

```
export function UserDropdown(props) {

const [value, setValue] = useState(null);
const defaultAdditional = {
        page: 1
};

const onChange = (e) => {
  props.getUserEmail(e)
  setValue(e)
}

<AsyncPaginate 
   additional={defaultAdditional}
   defaultValue={props.value}
   loadOptions={loadPageOptions}
   onChange={ (e) =>  onChange(e)}
/>
}
```

```
import UserDropdown from './userDropdown'

export class User extends Component { 

constructor(props) {
 super(props);
     this.state = {
       userEmail: ''
    }
}

onUserChange(e) {
 this.setState({userEmail: e.value})
}


<UserDropdown getUserEmail = { (email) =>  this.onUserChange(email)} value={this.state.userEmail} />

}
```

in loadPageOptions I am using the API's response.

Comment: Using `value` and `defaultValue` at the same time makes no sense. Either it is a controlled select (then you use `value`) or it is an uncontrolled select (then you can define a default with `defaultValue`). It can't be both. Please also show where `props.value` and `value` come from and what their initial values are.

Comment: @trixn I tried with only default but still it didn't work for me.

Comment: Only `defaultValue` is likely not what you want. You probably want only `value`. Please show where `value` is coming from and what its initial value is.

Comment: @trixn I have edited the code

Comment: See my example. You need to initialize your state with the default value instead of `null`. Also why do you have two states (one in `user` which by the way has to be `User` and one in `UserDropdown`)? State is only kept in a single place and passed as props if needed.

Comment: Actually I needed to call the api and had to show the response in dropdown at multiple places, so I created a separate component so I will just have to import it where it's needed. And in User component I have multiple fields in form but I copied a small part of code. Thanks

Comment: Yeah but that doesn't mean you need a separate state in each component. One state for all the inputs is enough. `UserDropdown` in your example doesn't need any state. It receives the value in props. I think you have a missunderstanding of when you need to use state and props.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to give a controlled select a default value you need to make sure that `value` initially is the default value. You can only use `defaultValue` if the select is uncontrolled meaning that it manages state of `value` internally:

```
const OPTIONS = [
  {
    value: 1,
    label: "Audi"
  },
  {
    value: 2,
    label: "Mercedes"
  },
  {
    value: 3,
    label: "BMW"
  }
];

const fakeData = async () => {
  await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));

  return {
    results: OPTIONS,
    has_more: false
  };
};

const loadOptions = async () => {
  const response = await fakeData();

  return {
    options: response.results,
    hasMore: response.has_more
  };
};

export default function App() {
  // this has to be initialized with the default value
  const [value, setValue] = useState({ value: 1, label: "Audi" });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <AsyncPaginate
        value={value}
        loadOptions={loadOptions}
        onChange={setValue}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit zen-swanson-iohdp]

Comment: Thanks, worked for me by. I am controlling the state from outside, so i had to remove all default props such as  defaultValue and defaultInputValue.